# jQuery load breaks function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My PHP webpage page1.php is like this:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
     function ciao(){
       $('#files').load('page2.php?SQL_type=files');
     }
     $(function(){
      $(".icon_files").bind("contextmenu",function(e){
       var left;
       var top;
       if($(document).width() < 630){
        left = 0;
        top = 0;
       }else{
        left = e.pageX;
        top = e.pageY;
       }
       $("#context").css({left: left, top: top});
       contextmenu($(this).attr('id'));
       e.preventDefault();
      });
     });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button onclick="ciao()">ciao</button>
  <div id="files">
   <?php
    $_GET['SQL_type'] = 'files';
    include "page2.php";
   ?>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I've build a custom contextmenu that appears with the code above.
When the page loads and include page2.php through PHP it works, but when I change #files content via jQuery, the contextmenu (and all other function I haven't copied there) no longer works.
I've tried other codes like

```
    jQuery.get('page2.php?SQL_type=files', null, function(data) {
      $('#files').append(data);
    }, 'html');
```

And I've tried also with simple Javascript

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("files").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "page2.php?SQL_type=files", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Inside page2.php there are simply some DIVs everyone of them with icon_files as class and it doesn't include jQuery again. It is simply like

```
<div class="icon_files">something</div><div class="icon_files">other</div>
```

I don't have any other ideas, what could be the problem here?
Thank you

Comment: The jquery code is running, however, the elements the jquery code is targeting are being replaced after clicking the button, thus causing them to lose events/data.

Comment: So should I re-add the events after the load is performed?

Comment: @FrancescoSorge You could but it would be simpler to just delegate these events

Comment: For those downvoting, please explain why. I know I'm not a genius like you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery code is running, however, the elements the jquery code is targeting are being replaced after clicking the button, thus causing them to lose events/data. Try using event delegation instead. This causes the event to be bound to the `id="files"` element rather than the elements that are being replaced.

```js
function ciao() {
  $('#files').html('<div class="icon_files">another icon...</div>');
}
$(function() {
  $("#files").on("contextmenu", ".icon_files", function(e) {
    var left;
    var top;
    if ($(document).width() < 630) {
      left = 0;
      top = 0;
    } else {
      left = e.pageX;
      top = e.pageY;
    }
    $("#context").css({
      left: left,
      top: top
    });
    console.log('context menu');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="ciao()">ciao</button>
  <div id="files">
    <div class="icon_files">icon...</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```